# What is the quickest ay to enable fulltext support for Sqlite 3 on OS X?

Tags: macos, sqlite

Sqlite comes installed with OS X Developer Tools. What is the quickest/best way to upgrade or rebuild the default binary to support Sqlite's fulltext features?

Comment: what version of OSX and sqlite3 do you have?
i.e, what do ...

uname -a

and

sqlite3 --version

say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sqlite3 library is included as part of OS X in `/usr/lib/`. You should never attempt to modify or replace OS X system libraries.  That could break your system and will likely get removed by a Software Update.  Instead, install a separate copy and link your applications to that.  For sqllite3, an easy solution is to install the [version from MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=sqlite3).  You could also just build your own and install it in `/usr/local/lib`.